# How to backfill partitioned data in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to backfill data from *GCP billing export* table to another table say T1.
Both tables are partitioned.
Below scheduled query runs everyday to get yesterday’s data.

`SELECT * FROM gcp_billing_export_v1 WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)`

Now I need to backfill the data , say for 15th May - how do I do that ?

I tried the backfill feature with the below query - expecting the backfill utility to take the past date i.e. May 15th as a param for the @run_date but that didn’t help.

`SELECT * FROM gcp_billing_export_v1 WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = @run_date`

The data is pulled for 15th May from the source table(gcp_billing_export_v1) but is populated against current date in the destination table i.e May 15th May data is populated against June 22nd in the destination table T1. Where am I going wrong ?
Any guidance ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using ingestion partitioning.

You would need to create a new table with the partitioning you want ie EventDate and populate that new table with historical and new daily data - as you can't overwrite an existing partition.

Link here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#query_an_ingestion-time_partitioned_table

Answer (score 2):

As @Lemon already pointed out that you're using `Ingestion time partitioned` tables(both source and dest), you need to understand how it works. Ingestion time partitioned tables are different from the [Regular partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#date_timestamp_partitioned_tables).

From the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#ingestion_time)-

> When you create a table partitioned by ingestion time,BigQuery automatically assigns rows to partitions based on the time when BigQuery ingests the data.
> This type of table has a `pseudo-column` named `_PARTITIONTIME`.The value of this column is the ingestion time for each row.

Since you are using the `SELECT * FROM gcp_billing_export_v1` you are getting all the data but without any `_PARTITIONTIME` column. And when you are saving the same result into the destination table , it is updating the `_PARTITIONTIME` column as per destintaion table's data `ingestion-time`.

Thus you have old data with the current date in `_PARTITIONTIME`

To avoid this your destination table needs to be either a normal table or regular partitioned table. 
Also you need to have an extra column to hold the `Datetime` value from the source's`_PARTITIONTIME` column.You can create a regular partition on this new column.

Then to get `_PARTITIONTIME` in your result set , in your quer you need to [mention the column name specifically](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#query_an_ingestion-time_partitioned_table) in your query.

```sql
SELECT *,_PARTITIONTIME AS ingestionTime 
FROM gcp_billing_export_v1 
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = @run_date
```

The above query will return all the data from the `gcp_billing_export_v1` table with 1 extra column `ingestionTime`.

Now you can backfill the data for 15th,May and save it to the new table.

You can also tweak around this below query to achieve the same

```
SELECT *,_PARTITIONTIME AS ingestionTime 
FROM gcp_billing_export_v1 
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

It will run daily as per your need .Now if you want to pull data for 15th,May then you have to schedule the backfill for 16th,May(as per the where clause)